# make rows to become columns in txt with powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have an input txt file with different data like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Current Local Time:             Fri Jul 01 04:54:27 2016

Current GMT Time:               Thu Jun 30 20:54:27 2016
Machine ID:                     6090
Machine Name:                   WL6090
Display S/N:                    0253G020TG
Terrain version:                5.3.843.843  
CAESTaskList DLL version:       5.3.843.843  
Application Type:               Terrain / CAES Ultra
Operating System:               1.04
Total RAM used by active files: 339.72 kB

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                                   Disk Space

Free Disk Space:  6758 MB               Total Disk Space:  7076 MB              

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 Current Local Time:    07-01-16, 04:54:27
 Current Service Hours: 314.41
```

And I have many such files every day.
I'm trying as a real newbie with powershell to grab only information I need from these files and I do it like this:

```
$Location = "D:\terrain_dia\Diag01Jul2016_045427.dia"
$a = Get-Content D:\terrain_dia\Diag01Jul2016_045427.dia

#Common
$option = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries

#ID
$LineID = Select-String -Path $Location -Pattern "Machine ID:" | Select-Object -Expand LineNumber
$ID = ($a)[$LineID-1]
$ID -replace '(?:\s|\r|\n)',''

#Name
$LineName = Select-String -Path $Location -Pattern "Machine Name:" | Select-Object -Expand LineNumber
$Name = ($a)[$LineName-1]
$Name -replace '(?:\s|\r|\n)',''

#SN
$LineSN = Select-String -Path $Location -Pattern "Display S/N:" | Select-Object -Expand LineNumber
$SN = ($a)[$LineSN-1]
$SN -replace '(?:\s|\r|\n)',''

#Version
$LineVersion = Select-String -Path $Location -Pattern "Terrain version:" | Select-Object -Expand LineNumber
$Version = ($a)[$LineVersion-1]
$Version -replace '(?:\s|\r|\n)',''

#RAM
$LineRam = Select-String -Path $Location -Pattern "Total RAM" | Select-Object -Expand LineNumber
$RAM = ($a)[$LineRam-1]
$RAM -replace '(?:\s|\r|\n)',''

#GPSSN
$LineGPSSN = Select-String -Path $Location -Pattern "GPS Receiver SN:" | Select-Object -Expand LineNumber
$GPSSN = ($a)[$LineGPSSN-1]
$GPSSN -replace '(?:\s|\r|\n)',''

#GPSType
$LineGPSType = Select-String -Path $Location -Pattern "GPS Receiver Type:" | Select-Object -Expand LineNumber
$GPSType = ($a)[$LineGPSType-1]
$GPSType -replace '(?:\s|\r|\n)',''

#NAV
$LineNAV = Select-String -Path $Location -Pattern "NAV firmware version:" | Select-Object -Expand LineNumber
$NAV = ($a)[$LineNAV-1]
$NAV -replace '(?:\s|\r|\n)',''

#SIG
$LineSig = Select-String -Path $Location -Pattern "SIG firmware version:" | Select-Object -Expand LineNumber
$SIG = ($a)[$LineSig-1]
$SIG -replace '(?:\s|\r|\n)',''

#ROM
$LineROM = Select-String -Path $Location -Pattern "ROM firmware version:" | Select-Object -Expand LineNumber
$ROM = ($a)[$LineROM-1]
$ROM -replace '(?:\s|\r|\n)',''
```

I'm getting the output:

```
MachineID:6090
MachineName:WL6090
DisplayS/N:0253G020TG
Terrainversion:5.3.843.843
TotalRAMusedbyactivefiles:339.72kB
GPSReceiverSN:3351J508SP
GPSReceiverType:MS992
NAVfirmwareversion:00506
SIGfirmwareversion:00506
ROMfirmwareversion:00425
FreeDiskSpace:6758MB
TotalDiskSpace:7076MB
```

So I have a fixed delimiter 
But what I really need to get is:

```
MachineID     MachineName      DisplayS/N 
6090          WL6090           0253G020TG
```

etc.

So I need to format this output as a table within txt file and then I'm going to put it te result into MS SQL db..

Please advise how can I format all these lines with powershell?

Any help will be very useful.

Thank you

Comment: Are you going to generate file and then put it into SQL Server? Wouldn't it be possible for you to put it directly into SQL Server?

Comment: Does this file always have one Machine information? Or could it have several MachineIDs?

Comment: If its to import into SQL server you would better to generate the SQL statements directly instead of formating it in columns. I can help you with this but when i run your code on my Windows 7 system I've got `Cannot index into a null array` errors and I won't spend my time to debug this :)

Comment: Thanks @ThomasG I guess thats because difference in powershell versionning.. I run it with Win 10.

Comment: @RigertaDemiri There is always only one Machine ID. So the story it - there are several machines and each of them have one such file.

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski if there is such option that would be great. But this is not the whole content from origin file. And I need to grab only some of content to put to db. I guess thats why I was not thinking about putting it to ms sql directly..

Comment: @ValeriyaPetrukhina just an idea, but if you gather some information and then store it in sql then why not gather it and run series of stored procedures/inserts directly from the script - all considering that you have access to mentioned server from were you run your script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one liner will process all *.dia files in the current folder and use a RegEx to filter all lines containing a colon and build condensed Name Value pairs and display them formatted:

```
Select-String .\*.dia -Pattern '^([^:]+):\s+(.*)$' | ForEach-Object { "{0,-20} {1,-25}: {2}" -f $_.FileName,$($_.Matches.Groups[1].Value -replace ' '), ($_.Matches.Groups[2].Value) }
```

Sample output:

```
Sample1.dia          CurrentLocalTime         : Fri Jul 01 04:54:27 2016
Sample1.dia          CurrentGMTTime           : Thu Jun 30 20:54:27 2016
Sample1.dia          MachineID                : 6090
Sample1.dia          MachineName              : WL6090
Sample1.dia          DisplayS/N               : 0253G020TG
Sample1.dia          Terrainversion           : 5.3.843.843
Sample1.dia          CAESTaskListDLLversion   : 5.3.843.843
Sample1.dia          ApplicationType          : Terrain / CAES Ultra
```

The following PowerShell script uses the same RegEx and Build a [PSCustomObject] and append all properties to it (at the moment with an error as `CurrentLocalTime` occurs twice in the files and TotalDiskSpace is on the same line as FreeDiskSpace)
Otherwise it Cumulates all data it finds in a file `CumulatedDia.Csv` saves it and reimports it to show content via `Out-GridView` I leave the two flaws for fixing by you/others.

```
$CumDia = ".\CumulatedDia.Csv"
Remove-Item $CumDia -ErrorAction Ignore

ForEach($File IN (Get-ChildItem *.dia)){
    $DiaFile = $Null
    $DiaFile = [PSCustomObject]@{'FileOrigin' = $File}
    Select-String -Path $File -Pattern '^([^:]+):\s+(.*)$' | ForEach-Object {
        $DiaFile | Add-Member -EA SilentlyContinue `
            -NotePropertyName ($_.Matches.Groups[1].Value -replace ' ')`
            -NotePropertyValue $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value
    } 
    $DiaFile | fl
    $DiaFile | Export-Csv -Path $CumDia -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
Import-Csv $CumDia|Out-GridView
```

Unwanted properties/columns may be removed with a Select-Object.
This is the Format-List output of the one row table

```
FileOrigin                : Q:\Test\2017\07\25\Sample1.dia
CurrentLocalTime          : Fri Jul 01 04:54:27 2016
CurrentGMTTime            : Thu Jun 30 20:54:27 2016
MachineID                 : 6090
MachineName               : WL6090
DisplayS/N                : 0253G020TG
Terrainversion            : 5.3.843.843
CAESTaskListDLLversion    : 5.3.843.843
ApplicationType           : Terrain / CAES Ultra
OperatingSystem           : 1.04
TotalRAMusedbyactivefiles : 339.72 kB
FreeDiskSpace             : 6758 MB               Total Disk Space:  7076 MB
CurrentServiceHours       : 314.41
GPSReceiverSN             : 3351J508SP
GPSReceiverType           : MS992
NAVfirmwareversion        : 00506
SIGfirmwareversion        : 00506
ROMfirmwareversion        : 00425
```

Sample Out-GridView pciture[image]

Comment: Thank you @LotPings. Sorry for late reply. I'm checking it now.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing documents like this can be a bit annoying, but the above is quite straightforward.

```
$InputFile.replace("MB","MB`n") -split "\n" |
    Select-String ":" | % {
        $_.Line.Trim() -replace ":\s+","`t"
    } | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Header "Detail","Value"
```

This gets the input as a string, then:

- puts a newline in after the `MB` values, since there's more than one on a single line.
- Selects only lines which have a `:` in them, to exclude garbage and whitespace.
- Trims the result, and then formats the values into a tab-separated CSV by replacing the `:____` part in the middle with a tab.
- Converts it into a CSV with headers for easy processing.

Results:

```
Detail                         Value                   
------                         -----                   
Current Local Time             Fri Jul 01 04:54:27 2016
Current GMT Time               Thu Jun 30 20:54:27 2016
Machine ID                     6090                    
etc...
```

you can get a long-form output then by using this:

```
$c.Detail -join "`t"
$c.Value -join "`t"
```

Hopefully this helps, I've used the code (not including the `MB` -> `MB\n` part) to parse similar log files a handful of times.

Comment: Thanks ConnorLSW. I'll check and get back to you

Comment: I do like this: `$InputFile = 'D:\terrain_dia\out.txt'
$InputFile.replace("MB","MB`n") -split "\n" |
    Select-String ":" | % {
        $_.Line.Trim() -replace ":\s+","`t"
    } | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Header "Detail","Value"` and I'm getting the result like this: `Detail                 Value
------                 -----
D:\terrain_dia\out.txt ` What am I doing wrong?)

Comment: you'll need to do `$InputFile = Get-Content 'D:\terrain_dia\out.txt'` to pull the text out of the file first.